# Boost Date_Time problem compiling a simple program

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

I'm writing a very stupid program using Boost Date_Time library.

```
int main(int srgc, char** argv) {
   using namespace boost::posix_time; 
   date d(2002,Feb,1); //an arbitrary date 
   ptime t1(d, hours(5)+nanosec(100)); //date + time of day offset 
   ptime t2 = t1 - minutes(4)+seconds(2);
   ptime now = second_clock::local_time(); //use the clock 
   date today = now.date(); //Get the date part out of the time 
}
```

Well I cannot compile it, compiler does not recognize a type...
Well I used many features of Boost libs like serialization and more... I correctly built them and, looking in my /usr/local/lib folder I can see that libboost_date_time.so is there (a good sign which means I was able to build that library)

When I compile I write the following:

> g++ -lboost_date_time main.cpp

But the errors it showed me when I specify the lib are the same of those ones where I do not specify any lib.

What is this? Anyone knows?

The error is

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int,
>   char**)’: main.cpp:9: error: ‘date’
>   was not declared in this scope
>   main.cpp:9: error: expected ‘;’ before
>   ‘d’ main.cpp:10: error: ‘d’ was not
>   declared in this scope main.cpp:10:
>   error: ‘nanosec’ was not declared in
>   this scope main.cpp:13: error:
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘today’

Comment: Cannot help without error messages.

Comment: Where are your boost libs installed ? Add a -L/path/to/boost/shared/libs

Comment: Paste the error and the exact command line you are running. And please provide us also with information about what architecture/platform you are compiling this on and for.

Comment: Well it simply does not recognizes types... tells me no type called....

Comment: The command line is the one shown in the question. I underline that Iam using in this project other libraries from boost like asio, serizlization ,thread, mpi... they work and some of them must be built... This means that Boost libraries are installed and correctly linked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I can't figure out what's `ss` in your code,
qualifying `date` and `Feb` as the following will make your code valid.

```
boost::gregorian::date
boost::date_time::Feb
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well... I just didn't use a correct using namespace in order to simplify the code... You were very helpful even if it does not seem so... thanks :)